# How can i print recutsive calls with Decorator

Tags: python, recursion, printing, decorator

I have a basic fib function and I want to create a Decorator in order to print the calls fib does

I want to print the calls without change the recursive function

for example:

```
for n = 5: # Thats the general idea
    fib(5)
    fib(4), fib(3)
    fib(3), fib(2), fib(2), fib(1)
    fib(2), fib(1), fib(1), fib(0), fib(1), fib(0), fib(0), fib(-1)
```

```
def print_call_params(function):
    def rec(params):
        if params:
            print(f"{function.__name__}({params})")
            function(params)

    return rec


@print_call_params
def fib(n):
    if n < 3: return 1
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

The end goal is to create a file where I can see the Tree that was created by the recursion

Comment: Ok, what errors/problems are you facing?

Comment: You can't accomplish that way of output you described because you are using depth recursion algorithm, which will go like 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 <- 3 -> 1 <-4 -> 2 and etc, which is hardly suitable for what you wan't. But the problem of your code is that your `rec()` does not return the result (which results in None returned causing error when summing Nones up)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is a missing `return`:

```
def print_call_params(function):
    def rec(params):
        if params:
            print(f"{function.__name__}({params})")
            return function(params) #<- need to return
    return rec
```

Also, I think the `if params:` is superfluous.